# How to set an optional parameter?

Tags: bash

Suppose you have the following problem:

Depending on if a script is executed within a pipe or not, you want to append the `-print0` parameter to `find`.

I can think of at least two ways to do this:

```
[[ -p '/dev/stdin' ]] && local null_terminated='-print0'
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! \( "${args[@]}" \) "$null_terminated"
```

Or

```
    if [[ -p '/dev/stdin' ]]; then
        find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! \( "${args[@]}" \) -print0
    else
        find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! \( "${args[@]}" \)
    fi
```

Is there any better way to do this? The question is for `bash`, but solutions for other shells or portable/standard `sh` solutions would be welcome as well.

Comment: Everybody could tell you it's own answer. I think your question is unlikely to be resolved. in my opinion the second form is better though

Comment: I agree with Kiwi - too subjective. Personally, though, I might do something like fn() { local pipechk=-print0 ; ... ; [ ! -p /dev/stdin ] && pipechk= ; ... find $args $pipechk ; }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one won't work as if `$null_terminated` is empty or unset, `find` will complain about that empty extra argument.

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! \( "${args[@]}" \) $null_terminated
```

Would work but only if `$null_terminated` doesn't contain any wildcard characters or characters from IFS.

Doing it:

```
if [[ -p '/dev/stdin' ]]; then
  extra_args=(-print0)
else
  extra_args=()
fi

find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! \( "${args[@]}" \) "${extra_args[@]}"
```

wouldn't have the problem.

Bourne/POSIXly, you could do:

```
set -- find . ! -name . -prune ! \( "$@" \)
[ -p /dev/stdin ] && set -- "$@" -exec printf '%s\0' {} +
"$@"
```

For one argument:

```
unset extra_arg; [ -p /dev/stdin ] && extra_arg=-print0
find . ! -name . -prune ! \( "$@" \) ${extra_arg+"$extra_arg"}
```

(note that `-print0` is not POSIX).