# Problem with passing parameters containing spaces and wild card characters

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh, quoting

I have a problem passing parameters if the parameters may contain wildcards and/or spaces, if those parameters are optional. Since this sounds pretty abstract, let's have a small example: The following shell script `some_command.sh` expects 2 or 3 arguments. The first argument is supposed to be a command line switch, the second argument is optional and, if present, must be a command line switch of the form `--NAME=VALUE`, and the final argument is required and can be anything:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This is file some_command.sh
# Synopsis:
# some_command.sh --switch1=val1 [--switch2=val2] arg
echo "switch1: $1"
shift
if [[ "$1" == --*=* ]]
then
  echo "switch2 ($1) detected"
  shift
fi
echo argument is ${1:?argument missing}
```

Let's assume that I am calling `some_command.sh` from some other script, `caller.sh`, in the following way:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This is file caller.sh
if [[ ${1:-x} == x ]]
then
  switch="--abc=long argument"
else
  switch=""
fi
some_command.sh "--exclude=*~" "$switch" arg
```

Note the quoting. The quotes around `--exclude` are necessary, because the wildcard expression must not be expanded by the shell, and the quotes around `"$switch"` are necessary, because `$switch` may contain text having spaces, and the argument must not be broken up on the spaces.

The intention is that if we execute `caller.sh x`, this should result into

```
some_command.sh "--exclude=*~" "--abc=long argument"  arg
```

and if we execute, say, `caller.sh y`, this should turn into

```
some_command.sh "--exclude=*~" arg
```

The `caller.sh` which I have provided here, does **not** work correctly, because in the latter case, it would execute

```
some_command.sh "--exclude*~" "" arg
```

which is incorrect.

I tried to prefix the command with `eval`. While this would solve the problem with `$switch`, it would also remove the quotes around `"--exclude"`, and the wildcards would be evaluated by the shell.

I guess I could go on with the `eval`, and just use an extra level of quoting, i.e. `"\"--exclude*~\""`, but this is an awful solution. I wonder if somebody has a cleaner way to do it.

In case you wonder why I came to this question: I stumbled over the problem when writing scripts invoking `zip`, and since these scripts should be able to cope with spaces in file names.

BTW, the problem, as stated, occurs with `bash` and `zsh`. I am also interested in clever solutions, which work only with one of those shells.

Comment: Similar: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119689

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array since that can expand to a variable number of arguments:

```
#! /bin/bash -
# This is file caller.bash
switch=()
if [[ ${1-x} == x ]]
then
  switch=("--abc=long argument")
fi
some_command.sh "--exclude=*~" "${switch[@]}" arg
```

Or you could use the `${var+...}` syntax:

```
#! /bin/sh -
# This is file caller.sh
unset switch
if [ "${1-x}" = x ]
then
  switch="--abc=long argument"
fi
some_command.sh "--exclude=*~" ${switch+"$switch"} arg
```

Note that with zsh, you can do:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
switch=
if [ "${1-x}" = x ]
then
  switch="--abc=long argument"
fi
some_command.sh "--exclude=*~" $switch arg
```

`zsh` doesn't do *split+glob* upon parameter expansion, but it does *empty removal* which is what you want here.